# Actor references in scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka.net, actor-model

What is the difference between    `/user/master/"+startID` and `/user/master/*`?
Im assuming the * means that the `StartRouteProcess` message is going to sent to all the actors. Is this correct?
Whereas,  `/user/master/"+startID`  sends the `Task` message to the actor with the given `startID`

```
      case JoinNode =>
        val startID = Nodelist(Random.nextInt(numJoined))
        context.system.actorSelection("/user/master/" + startID) ! Task("Join", startID, Nodelist(numJoined), -1)

      case BeginRouting =>
        println("Node Join Finished.\n")
        println("Routing started.")
        context.system.actorSelection("/user/master/*") ! StartRouteProcess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to akka document https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html#querying-the-logical-actor-hierarchy:

> Selections may be formulated using the ActorSystem.actorSelection and ActorContext.actorSelection methods and do support sending messages:

> `context.actorSelection("../*") ! msg`

> will send msg to all siblings including the current actor.

So you're correct.